# Add filtered query results to a screen in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a greenfield Lightswitch 2012 RC application with three tables:  problems, products, and versions.  When entering a problem, users need to first select from a list of all known products (working) and then select from a list of versions for the selected product.  There is a currently a relationship between problems-products, problems-versions, and products-versions.  How do I filter the list of versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a "cascading combobox", or a "nested combobox".

These two articles should help you:

[Nested AutoCompleteBox For Data Entry](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry/)

[Nested AutoCompleteBox for data entry Part 2](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry-part-2/)